# Why does pglm give different results thans log-plm?

Tags: panel-data, fixed-effects-model, count-data, poisson-regression, plm

I'm looking to regress a fixed-effects model on count data. My initial approach was to take the log of regressor on R's plm package. Then I found out about the pglm package, which enables general distributions (such as Poisson). While the two models give consistent results for time-varying variables, they provide contradictory results (i.e. significant opposite signs) when time-invariant variables are introduced. According to [Haussman et al. 1984](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1911191?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents), [Woolridge 2002](https://jrvargas.files.wordpress.com/2011/01/wooldridge_j-_2002_econometric_analysis_of_cross_section_and_panel_data.pdf) and [Alison 2009](https://us.sagepub.com/en-us/nam/fixed-effects-regression-models/book226025), results of these two models should be more or less similar. So what's going on?

```
library(plm, pglm)

data("PatentsRDUS", package="pglm”)

Poisson <- pglm(patents ~   log(rd)  + as.numeric(year)+ log(capital72)*center(as.numeric(year)) , PatentsRDUS,
           family = poisson(link=log), model = "within", index = c("cusip", "year"))

LogLin <- plm( log(patents+ 0.001) ~   log(rd)+ as.numeric(year)+center(log(capital72)*as.numeric(year)) , PatentsRDUS,
                model = "within", index = c("cusip", "year"))

summary(Poisson)

summary(LogLin)
```

Comment: does your patents variable have lots of values of 0,1,2? that's my first guess

Comment: @probabilityislogic Yes it does in this minimum example. However, the same thing happens in my initial problem where the response variable is averaged counts over 100 trials - i.e. very few 0, etc. Could there just be a bug in pglm?

Comment: @mpiktas Amicrazy or the pglm package could have a bug?

Comment: @SimonBerrebi I would try simulating from a synthetic data set generated by a process chosen by you and see if you can recover the ground truth. Then you'll know if it's a bug or not.